# Stateful EJB in business tier used in the conversation scope of the web tier

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I have an enterprise application with (at least) a web tier (UI only) and a service tier. In the service layer is all the business logic and the current conversation state implemented as `@Stateful @LocalBean` EJBs (no CDI).

This is somewhat similar to a `@SessionScoped` bean in terms of CDI, right?

So, here's the issue:
I have a long running conversation in the web tier (`@Named @ConversationScoped`) and want to access the Stateful EJB. The EJB should be accessed in different controllers (beans) of this conversation. I can't do it like this: `@EJB` because it would be a different instance of the particular EJB type. I have to save the reference to the EJB somehow. This is my current solution:

```
@EJB
private MyEJB _myEJB; // a stateful EJB

@Produces
@Builder // custom quallifier
@ConversationScoped
public MyEJB produceMyEJB() {
    return _myEJB;
}
```

Now I can access the same instance of the stateful EJB in each of the conversation scoped controllers like this `@Inject @Builder MyEJB _myEJB`.

It works, most of the time. But in some long running tests this reference is null and I don't know why.

I get this stack trace in the server.log of Glassfish:

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchObjectLocalException: The EJB does not exist. session-key:
907f0200001f-ffffffffc3388fbb-761
```

and/or

```
Cannot load from  BACKUPSTORE FOR Key: <907f0200001f-ffffffffc3388fbb-761>
```

Do You have any ideas why this happens? Thanks for help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Your stateful EJB is probably timing out. Check out `javax.ejb.StatefulTimeout`: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/StatefulTimeout.html

```
@Stateful
@StatefulTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 30)
public class MyEJB {
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your anwser. But there is no such StatefulTimeout anotation on the EJB. I figured out that the default configuration for this timeout (removing an unused EJB) is 90 minutes (see the EJB-container settings via localhost:4848). That's much more than the session timeout in the web.xml (and for conversations). Did I miss somthing?

Comment: You can set the timeout for a specific EJB using the @StatefulTimeout annotation, as shown in my example (a Java EE standard). If you want to change the default for all your stateful session beans, that is server-specific. I don't use Glassfish, but the removal-timeout-in-seconds attribute in glassfish-ejb-jar.xml might be what you're looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaqm.html